# Помогите пожалуйста дописать условие для запроса, чтоб он смог подсчитать месяца в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Подскажите, куда или как нужно записать условие чтобы он мне посчитал месяца у определённого клиента(redirect) и источника(source)? Мне надо знать сколько счетов было выставлено, а это считается по месяцам, тип январь и февраль это 2 счета, март апрель июнь 3 счета  и т.д. Я бы мог вместо count написать max но это не правильно, так как клиент может появиться в середине года, например в мая и у него будет стоять в значения максимального месяца.

Надеюсь понятно объяснил, если что отвечу в комментариях.

Вот мой запрос:

```
select TA.redirect, 
  count(case when TA.source='zlat1' then extract(month from TA.date) else 0 end) number_of_accounts_zlat1,  
  count(case when TA.source='zlat2' then extract(month from TA.date) else 0 end) number_of_accounts_zlat2,  
  sum(TA.result_for_the_day) accrued
from total_accounts TA
group by TA.redirect
```

Тут таблицы и данные + запрос --->https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b2b0f0242fbeab4d35656a7a71bd4fab

Comment: т.е. вам надо посчитать количество уникальных месяцев ? тогда count(distinct ...) правда если будет более 1 года то у вас все сломается

Comment: а как можно решить, если будет более 1 года?

Comment: Брать месяц и год от даты

Comment: я щас использовал distinct, он работает не так как мне надо :( Он ставит да же 1 если там вообще ничего нет @Mike

Comment: Значит что то не то считали. Обратите внимание count() считает все not null значения, если он считает 1 значит там есть одно не null значение

Comment: Собственно вот этот ваш 'else 0` и дает вам на выходе 1. Ведь 0 это не null и count его посчитает

Comment: count(distinct case when TA.source='zlat1' then extract(month from TA.date) end), @Mike подскажи пожалуйста как правильно по синтаксу добипсать год ? а то у меня везде ошибку выдает по синтаксу

Comment: `date_trunc('month', TA.date)` обрезает дату до месяца, получаете на выходе то же дату, но 1е число целевого месяца и года